# Why does this keep on giving me a list index out of range error?

Tags: python

```
count = 0
badIndices = [59,64,68,72,74,77,79,103,104,108,109,118,119,123,124,130,133,139]
test1 = []
csvCourses = []
csvExamTime = []
examTime = []

with open("final_exam_schedule.csv") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter = ",")
    next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        csvCourses.append(row)

for i in range(len(csvCourses)):
    csvExamTime.append(csvCourses[i][5])
    examTime.append(findSchedule(csvCourses[i][4],csvCourses[i][1],csvCourses[i][3],csvCourses[i][2]))

for i in badIndices:
    test1.append(csvCourses[i][5])

for i in badIndices:
    if count >= len(test1):
        break
    else:
        count += 1
        examTime[i] = test1[count] #this is where I get my error
```

every time I try to assign examTime[i] to test1, it gives me "out of range", but I thought that my if statement made sure that it didn't exceed the range?

For reference, examTime contains 155 different indices, and the badIndices list are the ones that aren't returning a value, so I'm going to that exact index and assigning it a value. findSchedule() is my function that has a bunch of ifs and elses to assign examTime, I didn't include it since it is really long and unnecessary to the problem. Only the specific bad indices don't return a value, the rest do.

edit: ok here is the findSchedule function

```
def findSchedule(days,time,cr,period):          
    if days == "TR":
        if time == "11:00":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Tuesday, December 13, 9:45 - 11:45 am")
            elif period == "PM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")     
        elif time == "12:30" or time == "1:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Tuesday, December 13, 12:00 - 2:00 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "3:30":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Tuesday, December 13, 2:15 - 4:15 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "5:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Tuesday, December 13, 4:30 - 6:30 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "6:30":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Tuesday, December 13, 7:00 - 9:00 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "8:00":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Wednesday, December 14, 7:30 - 9:30 am")
            elif period == "PM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "2:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Thursday, December 15, 12:00 - 2:00 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "9:30":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Friday, December 16, 9:45 - 11:45 am")
        elif time == "9:00":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Friday, December 16, 7:30 - 9:30 am")
        elif time == "10:00":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Wednesday, December 14, 9:45 - 11:45 am")
        elif time == "12:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Wednesday, December 14, 12:00 - 2:00 pm")
        elif time == "5:00" and cr == "5":
            return("Wednesday, December 14, 4:30 - 6:30 pm")
    elif days == "MWF":
        if time == "10:00":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Wednesday, December 14, 9:45 - 11:45 am")
            elif period == "PM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "12:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Wednesday, December 14, 12:00 - 2:00 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "3:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Wednesday, December 14, 2:15 - 4:15 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "5:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Wednesday, December 14, 4:30 - 6:30 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "6:30" or time == "8:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Wednesday, December 14, 7:00 - 9:00 pm")
            elif period == "AM" and time == "8:00":
                return("Thursday, December 15, 7:30 - 9:30 am")
        elif time == "11:00":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Thursday, December 15, 9:45 - 11:45 am")
            elif period == "PM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "2:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Thursday, December 15, 2:15 - 4:15 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "9:00":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Friday, December 16, 7:30 - 9:30 am")
            elif period == "PM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "1:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Friday, December 16, 12:00 - 2:00 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "4:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Friday, December 16, 2:15 - 4:15 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "8:00":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Thursday, December 15, 7:30 - 9:30 am")
        elif time == "9:30":
            return("Friday, December 16, 9:45 - 11:45 am")
        elif time == "3:30":
            return("Tuesday, December 13, 2:15 - 4:15 pm")
        elif time == "3:00":
            return("Wednesday, December 14, 2:15 - 4:15 pm")
        elif time == "11:00" and cr == "5":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Thursday, December 15, 9:45 - 11:45 am")
    elif days == "MW":
        if time == "8:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Wednesday, December 14, 7:00 - 9:00 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Thursday, December 15, 7:30 - 9:30 am")
        elif time == "11:00":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Thursday, December 15, 9:45 - 11:45 am")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "2:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Thursday, December 15, 2:15 - 4:15 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "1:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Friday, December 16, 12:00 - 2:00 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "10:00":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Wednesday, December 14, 9:45 - 11:45 am")
        elif time == "9:00":
            return("Friday, December 16, 7:30 - 9:30 am")
        elif time == "9:30":
            return("Friday, December 16, 9:45 - 11:45 am")
        elif time == "9:30":
            return("Friday, December 16, 9:45 - 11:45 am")
        elif time == "3:30":
            return("Tuesday, December 13, 2:15 - 4:15 pm")
        elif time == "6:30" and cr == "1":
            return("Monday, December 12, 6:30 - 7:25 pm")
        elif time == "6:30" and cr == "2":
            return("Monday, December 12, 6:30 - 8:20 pm")
        elif time == "6:30" and cr == "3":
            return("Monday, December 12, 6:30 - 9:30 pm")
        elif time == "6:30" and cr == "4":
            return("Monday, December 12, 6:30 - 10:15 pm")
        elif time == "5:00" and cr == "5":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Wednesday, December 14, 4:30 - 6:30 pm")

    elif days == "R":
        if time == "6:30" and period == "PM":
            return("Thursday, December 15, 7:00 - 9:00 pm")
    elif days == "WF":
        if time == "8:00" and (cr == "2" or cr == "5"):
            if period == "AM":
                return("Thursday, December 15, 7:30 - 9:30 am")
            elif period == "PM":
                return("No class found")
        elif time == "8:00" and cr == "4":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Wednesday, December 14, 7:30 - 9:30 am")
            elif period == "PM":
                return("Class not found")
        elif time == "9:00":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Friday, December 16, 7:30 - 9:30 am")
            if period == "PM":
                return("Class not found")
        elif time == "9:30":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Friday, December 16, 9:45 - 11:45 am")
            elif period == "PM":
                return("Class not found")
        elif time == "10:00":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Wednesday, December 14, 9:45 - 11:45 am")
            elif period == "PM":
                return("Class not found")
        elif time == "11:00":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Thursday, December 15, 9:45 - 11:45 am")
            elif period == "PM":
                return("Class not found")
        elif time == "12:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Wednesday, December 14, 12:00 - 2:00 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class not found")
        elif time == "12:30":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Tuesday, December 13, 12:00 - 2:00 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Classs not found")
        elif time == "1:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Friday, December 16, 12:00 - 2:00 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class not found")
        elif time == "2:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Thursday, December 15, 12:00 - 2:00 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class not found")
        elif time == "3:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Wednesday, December 14, 2:15 - 4:15 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class not found")
        elif time == "3:30":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Tuesday, December 13, 2:15 - 4:15 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class not found")
        elif time == "4:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Friday, December 16, 2:15 - 4:15 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class not found")
        elif time == "5:00" and cr == "2":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Tuesday, December 13, 4:30 - 6:30 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class not found")
        elif time == "5:00" and cr == "4":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Wednesday, December 14, 4:30 - 6:30 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class not found")
        elif time == "9:30":
            return("Friday, December 16, 9:45 - 11:45 am")
        elif time == "3:30":
            return("Tuesday, December 13, 2:15 - 4:15 pm")
    elif days == "M":
        if time == "6:30":
            return("Monday, December 12, 6:30 - 7:25 pm")
    elif days == "T":
        if time == "6:30":
            return("Tuesday, December 13, 7:00 - 9:00 pm")
    else:
        if (cr == "4" or cr == "2") and time == "12:30":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Tuesday, December 13, 1:00 - 2:00 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif cr == "4" and time == "3:30":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Tuesday, December 13, 2:15 - 4:15 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif cr == "4" and time == "5:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Tuesday, December 13, 4:30 - 6:30 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif cr == "4" and time == "8:00":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Wednesday, December 14, 7:30 - 9:30 am")
            elif period == "PM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "10:00":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Wednesday, December 14, 9:45 - 10:45 am")
            elif period == "PM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "12:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Wednesday, December 14, 12:00 - 2:00 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "3:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Wednesday, December 14, 2:15 - 4:15 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "5:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Wednesday, December 14, 2:15 - 4:15 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif cr == "5" and time == "8:00":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Thursday, December 15, 7:30 - 9:30 am")
            elif period == "PM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "11:00":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Thursday, December 15, 9:45 - 11:45 am")
            elif period == "PM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif cr == "4" and time == "2:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Thursday, December 15, 12:00 - 2:00 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif cr == "5" and time == "2:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Thursday, December 15, 2:15 - 4:15 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "9:00":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Friday, December 16, 7:30 - 9:30 am")
            elif period == "PM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "9:30":
            if period == "AM":
                return("Friday, December 16, 9:45 - 10:45 am")
            elif period == "PM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "1:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Friday, December 16, 12:00 - 2:00 pm")
            elif period == "PM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")
        elif time == "4:00":
            if period == "PM":
                return("Friday, December 16, 2:15 - 4:15 pm")
            elif period == "AM":
                return("Class final not found, please try again")   
        else:
            return("Class final not found, please try again")
```

Comment: try swapping the order of your last two lines. `count` effectively starts at 1 due to where it's located, while python indices start at 0.

Comment: also use print statements ... you surely would have found the solution

Comment: that fixed it! Another problem arose though, the values of examTime at the bad indices still return a "NoneType" value. Do you have any idea why this isn't working?

Comment: @AustinLutterbach Does `findSchedule` actually return anything? If so, what?

Comment: @jDo it returns a string which is the exam time. for example: "Wednesday 17, 7:45 - 8:00 am"

Comment: @jDo thats what its suppose to return anyway, it doesn't for those specific indices, and I'm not sure why. I've defined the function for the bad indices in several different ways for it to try to return the value, but it won't do it. So I'm trying to just append the bad indices values straight to the list

Comment: @AustinLutterbach Ok, I think we need to see the `findSchedule` function to help out.

Comment: @jDo posted it! its odd because even if it doesn't fit any conditions it should return the string "Class not found...", but it just returns "NoneType"

Comment: Could you try to provide a [mcve]?

Comment: @AustinLutterbach Thanks for including it. Just as an example, all the `if`/`elif` statements with no final `else` clause will return `None` if neither `if` nor `elif` are `True`. The function would benefit  from an overall re-factoring and shortening to reduce repetition and make it easier to follow the logic. You could start by replacing all the `return` statements with variable assignments and just have a single `return` at the end.

Comment: @cricket_007 I just called the findSchedule function for a bad index and it printed and returned the correct value. But when I loop through examTime it still returns "NoneType" value for that specific index.

Comment: @jDo ok thanks for the tip! I just tested calling the function though for a specific bad index, and it returned the correct value, so I don't think it is the function, but it is when I try to loop through examTime since for some reason it gives me the "NoneType

Comment: @AustinLutterbach Ok, try including the full error/traceback here as well.

Comment: @jDo It's not giving me an error, it just gives me None when I print out all of the schedules. So for example indices 1 - 58 will give me a exam time string, but when I get to 59, for some reason it gives me "none", even though it returns a value when I print out calling the function for that specific index.

Comment: my comment was simply that the method is really really long. What input are you giving that generates the unexpected results?

Answer (score 0):

It's tough to say without knowing what your data looks like, but here's what I think,

Your `count` variable is being incremented too early. In python list indexes start at `0` and go to `len(list)-1` as the last index. You're kind of starting at `count=1` so it's possible that on the last iteration `count=len(list)` which gives the error. Try this as a correction for the latter part of your code:

```
for i in badIndices:
    if count >= len(test1):
        break
    else:
        examTime[i] = test1[count]
        #We increment count after it is used
        #to avoid an error
        count+=1
```